# 64 bit Vs 32 bit Windows Seven

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I'm looking to build a new computer and was wondering what the difference is in 32 vs 64 bit Windows Seven. I do know that 64 bit allows for more RAM.

Also, will old programs run on a 64 bit machine? For example will World of Warcraft etc run on a 64 bit copy of Windows Seven?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2011/09/02/why-run-64-bit-windows.aspx

Answer (score 10):

**Differences**

- [Kernel Patch Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection)
- No support for [unsigned drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing).
- No support for 32 bit drivers.
- Hardware-backed [Data Execution Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention).<sup>1</sup>
- Higher maximum RAM.

Microsoft's website has [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946765) covering the differences in more detail.

**Compatibility**

Programs written without explicit 64 bit support should work on 64 bit Windows, since programs in the **Program Files (x86)** directory are emulated. If you want to know beforehand whether an old version of a program works in 64 bit Windows, you could look at the system requirements page in the [Wayback Machine](http://www.waybackmachine.org/).

Since Windows 7 at both 32 bit and 64 bit are sold together, you can always reinstall with 32 bit Windows if it turns out a program you really need only works on the 32 bit version.

<sup>1</sup> Some CPUs support this feature in 32 bit windows through [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) (as said by  grawity).

Comment: fwiw, many CPUs support hardware DEP and big RAM even in 32-bit mode -- through PAE.

Comment: CPUs may support more RAM in 32 bit mode, but Windows 7 doesn't. Only way to get mroe than ~3.5 GB of memory in Win7 is to use 64 bit.

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit has a nice feature for program compatibility called XP Mode.  Basically installs a free copy of XP on a virtual machine.  You can also install a lot of 32 bit software in a 64 bit environment.  Support for 64 bit has really moved forward, I wouldn't be afraid about taking the jump, plus as @Simon Brown pointed out, both 32 bit and 64 bit come together in same box.

Comment: I have been using 64-bit exclusively since Windows 7 came out. I would consider myself a power user, running lots of business and personal applications. I also often run various proprietary softwares that my clients use (so I can learn the software and test it.) I was quite surprised to have very little problems with 64-bit.

Comment: @James Watt, my story is about the same.  Vista took a lot of the punishment related to the growing pains of a 64 bit OS, the result is an excellent OS in Windows 7.

Comment: Always use 64-bit version. 32-bit generation is already over. In often, machines running Windows 7 carry >4GB RAM. Therefore, 64-bit W7 is needed.

Comment: I'm hoping that the next version of Windows will only be available as 64-bit. This will force the market to start actually producing 64-bit applications.

Comment: @typoknig, 7 is no better as a 64-bit OS than Vista; Vista took lots of punishment because there were few drivers for it.

Comment: You are delusional if you think W7 isn't better than Vista, but your second statement about drivers was my point exactly.

Comment: 32-bit programs really are not emulated on 64-bit. WoW64 provides thin transition API for 32-bit <-> 64-bit kernel calls. The thread(s) in your 32-bit program run native on the CPU in 32-bit mode. AMD64 supports simultaneous 64-bit and 32-bit code segments. Emulation is much-much slower, this happens in Windows if you are running on IA-64 (Itanium 2 CPUs); see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

Answer (score 0):

World of warcraft will run fine on win7 x64. As will 99% of software that supports XP (common software anyways). Anything not x64 will be emulated.

There isn't that much that will not run on x64 except some older drivers.  But if those drivers don't support x64 chances are they don't support Vista or Win 7 anyways.  Software problems on Win7 is very rare and at worst you may have to use compatability modes.

I would go with x64,  there are very few reason not to.